# Trim string with multiple chars

Tags: c#, string, split, char

I'm trying to trim a string with multiple chars, but isn't working for `,`.

Code:

```
static String xpto(String[] a) 
{  
    string trimming;

    foreach (string value in a)
    {
        //...
        trimming = value.Trim(new Char[] { '(', ',', ')' });
        //...
    }
}
```

> Sample input: (1,2)
>
> Output expected: 12
>
> What I'm getting: 1,2

Maybe some conflict with ', ', '? Don't know why it doesn't works!
I could use `split()` 3 times (one for each char) to reach where I want, but I'm confused why this does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Trim()` only removes characters at the beginning and end of a string. In your example `"(1,2)"` the comma exists in the middle of the string.

Instead, use `.Replace(",", "").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "");`

Comment: So simple, I should have done some reading about Trim. Thank you @Dai
I will accept the question, when the time goes out.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regular expressions to replace the unwanted characters. In this case, the regex @"[(,)]+" will replace the chars '(', ')' and ',' to an empty string. It's more elegant.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

trimming = Regex.Replace(value, @"[(,)]+", String.Empty);
```